# Should I really need the "InProgress" flag while polling my database?

Tags: java, sql, database, multithreading

I'm implementing an event listener, querying new items to process, by creationTime in ascending order.
I deal with multithreading.

My current workflow is:

1. Querying a batch of items (let's say 50) containing the "New" flag.
2. Looping through those items, and for each item, updating its status to "InProgress".
3. For each item, still within the loop, start the corresponding process, detached in a thread (using Akka Actors in my case).
4. As soon as a process is fully completed, update the item's flag to "Consumed".

I set a polling frequency of 3 seconds, that obviously may involve query of new items BEFORE the current retrieved items are being fully processed (due to multithreading), with the flag "Consumed" set.
Only the querying is single-threaded, otherwise it would lead to retrieve duplicates.

**I wonder if the step 2 is essential: updating each item with "InProgress" flag.**
Indeed, it would slow down the whole.

I thought about skipping this step but to ensure that futures queries don't retrieve items that are currently being processed (let's imagine a very long computation), I would NOT start the next retrieval query as soon as the whole batch is processed.
Basically, my query step would wait for workers to finish their current jobs.
Obviously, this would make sense if the kind of jobs are similar in computation time.

What is a good practice of polling database while dealing with multithreaded computation?

Comment: A good practice is to avoid polling at all, but sometimes, one's hand is forced.

Comment: Just a thought...by why loop for each record?  If you can elminate that step, you should be able to go from 'new', process all records at once, then set as consumed.

Comment: @Twelfth What if the dispatching to workers happens and then immediately the next retrieval query happens BEFORE the tasks finished to be processed with the "Consumed" flag set. The query would then retrieve those tasks again, since they are still flag as "New", leading to duplication of computation.

Comment: @MarsAtomic A database polling may be necessary in the case of building an event store. (Vaughn Vernon in his "IDDD" book)

Comment: Hmmm...not sure then, though there might be a solution found in row locking here...though I wouldn't know what.  Updating to inprogress without the loop might speed that up a bit.

Comment: IMHO, updating the items to InProgress is the process that slows down. Looping over 50 items... I don't think so. CPUs are fast enough.  I'm using looping since I could have distinct kind of events that would be dispatched to different workers. For instance "CreatedItemEvent", "UpdatingItemEvent" etc.. that demands different nature of workers.

Comment: one update of 50 records is much faster than 50 updates of one record at any rate...maybe you can change the update statement to do it by ID list in the first step (query batch of items) instead of setting in progress as part of the loop.  Outside of that, sorry..you've reeached the limits of what I know here ;)